# Necesito hacer esto mismo con TypeScript

Tags: ionic, typescript

Tengo el siguiente código en el script java y funciona perfectamente pero necesito pasarlo a ionic con typescrpt y no almacena el array.

No sé cómo trabajar el elemento `document.getElementsByClassName ('movil');`
en typeScript

```
var piezas = document.getElementsByClassName('movil');

for(var i=0;i<piezas.length;i++){
    piezas[i].setAttribute("width", tamWidh[i]);
    piezas[i].setAttribute("height",tamHeight[i]);
    piezas[i].setAttribute("x", Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) +1));
    piezas[i].setAttribute("y", Math.floor((Math.random() * 409) +1));
    piezas[i].setAttribute("onmousedown","seleccionarElemento(evt)");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript es un superconjunto tipado de JavaScript y `getElementsByClassName` funciona sin problemas. Por otra parte, el código que compartes presenta "errores" que harán que TypeScript no compile. Te recomiendo que vayas al [área de pruebas de TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) para probar el código.

Automáticamente podrás ver [los errores](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20piezas%20%3D%20document.getElementsByClassName('movil')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afor(var%20i%3D0%3Bi%3Cpiezas.length%3Bi%2B%2B)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20piezas%5Bi%5D.setAttribute(%22width%22%2C%20tamWidh%5Bi%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20piezas%5Bi%5D.setAttribute(%22height%22%2CtamHeight%5Bi%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20piezas%5Bi%5D.setAttribute(%22x%22%2C%20Math.floor((Math.random()%20*%2010)%20%2B1))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20piezas%5Bi%5D.setAttribute(%22y%22%2C%20Math.floor((Math.random()%20*%20409)%20%2B1))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20piezas%5Bi%5D.setAttribute(%22onmousedown%22%2C%22seleccionarElemento(evt)%22)%3B%0D%0A%7D):

1. `tamWith` no está definido (esto seguramente es un falso positivo).
2. `tamHeight` no está definido (esto seguramente es otro falso positivo).
3. `setAttribute` necesita que el parámetro pasado sea de tipo String, pero con `Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) +1)` estás asignando un Number.
4. `setAttribute` necesita que el parámetro pasado sea de tipo String, pero con `Math.floor((Math.random() * 409) +1)` estás asignando un Number.

La solución entonces sería definir las variables `tamWith` y `tamHeight` (que me imagino que ya están definidas, pero no incluidas en el snippet compartido, sólo asegúrate que `tamWith` es correcta y no `tamWidth`), y pasar un String en lugar de un número a `setAttribute`, algo que puedes hacer usando `toString`.

Corrigiendo eso, el código ya [funciona y compila sin errores](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20piezas%20%3D%20document.getElementsByClassName('movil')%3B%0D%0Avar%20tamWidh%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0Avar%20tamHeight%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0Afor(var%20i%3D0%3Bi%3Cpiezas.length%3Bi%2B%2B)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20piezas%5Bi%5D.setAttribute(%22width%22%2C%20tamWidh%5Bi%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20piezas%5Bi%5D.setAttribute(%22height%22%2CtamHeight%5Bi%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20piezas%5Bi%5D.setAttribute(%22x%22%2C%20Math.floor((Math.random()%20*%2010)%20%2B1).toString())%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20piezas%5Bi%5D.setAttribute(%22y%22%2C%20Math.floor((Math.random()%20*%20409)%20%2B1).toString())%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20piezas%5Bi%5D.setAttribute(%22onmousedown%22%2C%22seleccionarElemento(evt)%22)%3B%0D%0A%7D):

```
var piezas = document.getElementsByClassName('movil');
var tamWidh = [];
var tamHeight = [];

for(var i=0;i<piezas.length;i++){
    piezas[i].setAttribute("width", tamWidh[i]);
    piezas[i].setAttribute("height",tamHeight[i]);
    piezas[i].setAttribute("x", Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) +1).toString());
    piezas[i].setAttribute("y", Math.floor((Math.random() * 409) +1).toString());
    piezas[i].setAttribute("onmousedown","seleccionarElemento(evt)");
}
```